# to print line starting with desire number

Tags: patterns

I have some query relating to some files.

Inputs :

```
A=”1n”
List=”R1  7n  3n”  “R2  8n  1n”  “R3  1n  2n”  “R4  2n  3n”  “R5  3n  4n”
```

In output I want new list should start with the string having `1n` information. New list:

```
“R2 8n 1n” “R3 1n 2n” “R4 2n 3n” “R5 3n 4n”
```

Please confirm can I do it with the help of Shell commands operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain what is `“` quotes? Is it usual `"`? If not - just substitute it in scripts.

If you can modify `file1` to `"[^"]1n.*` it would be easy use `grep`

```
grep -of file1 file2 > file3
```

If not you are free to use `sed`

```
grep -o "$(sed -E 's/(.)(.*)(.)/\1[^\3]*\2.*/' file1)" file2 > file3
```

or even `read`

```
grep -o "$(read -r r <file;q=${r%${r#?}};printf "$q[^$q]*${r//["]/}.*")" file2 > file3
```